# FFmpeg output sent to v4l2loopback video device won't be read by guvcview

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, loopback, v4l2

I set a dummy camera `/dev/video1` with v4l2loopback module.

I can read the stream with `ffplay`, `vlc` or even `zoom` of this camera when I send to it contentwith **`ffmpeg`**:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input-file.mp4 -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

Redirecting a real camera to the dummy works too:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

However, when I try to Guvcview (2.0.6), I still get the error "Invalid pixel format", then the error "invalid resolution index". **Guvcview works with the real camera** (`video0`).

So I checked both cameras with the command `v4l2-ctl --list-formats`:

- `video0` (true camera)

  ```
    ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
            Index       : 0
            Type        : Video Capture
            Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
            Name        : YUYV 4:2:2

            Index       : 1
            Type        : Video Capture
            Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
            Name        : Motion-JPEG
  ```
- `video1` (fake one)

  ```
    ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
            Index       : 0
            Type        : Video Capture
            Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
            Name        : YUYV 4:2:2
  ```

They both accept the pixel format `YUV 4:2:2`. So I passed `-pix_fmt yuyv422` to ffmpeg (and tried other formats)  to explicitely use this as pixel format output (so after the `-i input-y` argument) but it didn't worked neither.

Am I missing something?